# Understanding Ajax request with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax

I currently have an Ajax request that I don't fully understand the behavior it's giving me. First, I'm not sure what the `url` is doing? Am I saying that is where it redirects after the call or that is the url of where it needs to be? I'll post the code and explain along the way.

### AJAX

```
 $(document).on('click','.delete-snitch', function() {

    var snitchID = $(this).attr('data-snitch-id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/snitches/' + snitchID,
        success: function(){
            $('#tr-for-snitch-' + snitchID).fadeOut
        }
    });
});
```

See the url? When I use this as is I get a 404 error that the snitch was not found? I'm not sure why. but if I just have it render the snitch index page it still makes a page refresh which of course is not what I want. My question is -> What is the url doing in my case?

### CONTROLLER

```
    def destroy
    DestroySnitch.perform(snitch: @snitch)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        redirect_to snitches_path, notice: "Snitch was successfully deleted."
      end
      format.js do
        binding.pry
      end
    end
  end
```

When I try to make the call and put a binding pry in the block for format.js it doesn't hit it? Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

### FORM

```
 <%= form_for @snitch, html: { class: "form-actions", method: 'delete' } do |form| %>
 <span class="button-text"><%= link_to 'NO WAY!', home_base_url_or_default(root_path), rel: "modal:close" %></span>
 <input type="submit" class="button button--modal delete-snitch" data-snitch-id="<%= @snitch.token %>" value="Yes, delete it.">
 <% end %>
```

Comment: The `url` option sets the path for the initial request. Though, from that, Ajax will attempt to follow any redirect responses (status 301 or 302) that it receives while handling the request. To see each request individually, use the "Network" panel in your browser's developer tools (note: you may need to enable keeping entries through navigation).

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you are saying. As it stands right now it still responds to the html and does a page refresh. Is there anything I should try that you can see? I'm new to javascript and debugging issues

Comment: Please show the html for the '.delete-snitch' element. It seems like you're mixing up jQuery to handle clicking on the element and having the controller respond to an ajax request. If the element is set up as a form, just add remote: true as an option and you won't need to listen for the event click.

Comment: @margo I update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default action for that form is to send a 'post' request which results in a page refresh. Since you are handling the post request in your click function, you need to prevent the default action which is as simple as adding prevent_default to that function. You may want to change the function to listen for the form being submitted

```
 $(document).on('submit','.delete-snitch', function(event) {

   var snitchID = $(this).attr('data-snitch-id');
   $.ajax({
     type: 'DELETE',
     url: '/snitches/' + snitchID,
     success: function(){
       $('#tr-for-snitch-' + snitchID).fadeOut
     }
   });

   event.prevent_default();
 });
```

Rails has [some helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) to work with AJAX which are worth reading.